# Removing newline characters from foreign language column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in an SQL Server 2012 database with a column defined as `Note (ntext, NOT NULL)`. This column contains free text (with newlines and special characters) in multiple languages (English, Asian and European).

I'm saving the results of queries on this table in a CSV and I'd like to remove newlines from this column beforehand. In order to use `REPLACE`, I have to convert the column from `ntext` to `varchar`, like so:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(note.Note as varchar(max)), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') Note
```

But then the foreign characters are lost and replaced with `?`. How can I remove newlines while preserving language encoding?

Comment: Oh silly me! I never realized `REPLACE` works with `nvarchar`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Never use ntext. It's deprecated. Infact, I'm surprised to see sql server 2012 supports it.